# SQL Server Query filter query - NULL parameter

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server database question.

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [PhaseID] [INT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable 
VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, NULL)
```

I am running a SQL query which is supposed to retrieve the record which matches the `PhaseId` column exactly (it could be null or an integer).. but seem to be missing something.

```
DECLARE @ID INT, @PhaseID INT

SET @ID = 1
SET @PhaseID = 1

SELECT * 
FROM TestTable
WHERE PhaseID = @PhaseID OR @PhaseID IS NULL
```

If `@PhaseID` parameter is integer this works fine.

```
DECLARE @PhaseID INT 
SET @PhaseID = 1 --works
```

But if `@PhaseID` is null, it returns all the records whereas I need the query to return only the first record & 4th record.

```
DECLARE @PhaseID INT 
SET @PhaseID = NULL

SELECT * 
FROM TestTable
WHERE PhaseID = @PhaseID OR @PhaseID IS NULL -- does not work returns all 4 records
```

How can this be achieved please?

I have referred a few other questions already but have not been successful.
[SQL Query Where Clause for Null OR Match (only return 1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374751/sql-query-where-clause-for-null-or-match-only-return-1)

Comment: Check the column not the variable: `Where PhaseID IS NULL` not `Where @PhaseID IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `PhaseID` instead of `@PhaseID` :

```
Select * 
from TestTable
Where (PhaseID = @PhaseID OR PhaseID IS NULL);
```

However, i would over thinking with :

```
. . .
WHERE (@PhaseID IS NOT NULL AND PhaseID = @PhaseID) OR
      (@PhaseID IS NULL AND PhaseID IS NULL);
```

Comment: (@PhaseID IS NOT NULL AND PhaseID = @PhaseID) OR
      (@PhaseID IS NULL AND PhaseID IS NULL) works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @PhaseID INT
SET @PhaseID = 1

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE '

IF @PhaseID IS NOT NULL
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'PhaseID = @_PhaseID'
ELSE
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'PhaseID IS NULL'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql,N'@_PhaseID int',@_PhaseID = @PhaseID
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently you are doing `@PhaseID` is `NULL` which brings back 4 rows because you are referencing the parameter for the IS NULL check.

```
Declare @PhaseID int
SET @PhaseID = NULL

Select * 
from #Data
Where PhaseID = @PhaseID OR @PhaseID IS NULL
```

This brought back row 1 & 4 by using PhaseID as the column reference rather than referencing the parameter.

```
Select * 
from #Data
Where PhaseID = @PhaseID OR PhaseID IS NULL
```

Comment: But op wants 2 rows (1 & 4)

Comment: @AlexK. Amended the answer. Cheers.

Comment: This isn't going to work, you're going to get the `NULL` records when `@PhaseID` is set to an integer.